# three.js - Get all objects(meshes) in the area (3d cube)

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a system of tubes. More precisely, I create a tubes from this code

***tube_color** - obviously, color of tube,*
***spline_points** - huge number of THREE.Vector3 objects,*
***segments**, **radiusSegments** are just numbers*

```
    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: tube_color, shading: THREE.SmoothShading } );
    var spline = new THREE.SplineCurve3(spline_points);
    var tube = new THREE.TubeGeometry(spline, segments, 10, radiusSegments, false, false);
    var tubeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(tube, material);
    scene.add(tubeMesh);
```

This code creates one particular mesh object in space. For each mesh I can have an array of Vector3's by using *myMesh*.geometry.vertices.
**The problem is**: I have the point in 3d space. Around this point I create Cube, which *does* intersect with tubes. For example, this cube can be created like this

```
    var cube = new THREE.CubeGeometry(xSize,ySize,zSize, 5, 5, 5);
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0xff0000,
        opacity: 1,
        wireframe: true,
        transparent: false
    });
    var selectionMesh = new THREE.Mesh(cube, material);
    scene.add(selectionMesh);
```

**Is it possible at least to find objects(meshes) that have intersection with by cubic area?** I know that in **scene** object I have all meshes, and I can iterate over them, get vertices, iterate over them with a condition if there is at least one its point is in cubic area. <strike>But I believe</strike>... I hope there is a method/algorithm<strike>/magic</strike> much more simple then this...

Comment: If you have a lot of points, an octree may help: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_octree.html.

Comment: Ok, thank you for idea, I will check this on upcoming week.

Comment: @WestLangley, thank you very much! It works almost perfect! Sorry for the delay - I was trying different approaches for this problem. Could you help me with octree as well:   
`meshesSearch = octree.search( rayCaster.ray.origin, radiusSphere, true, rayCaster.ray.direction );`  
and it shows to me for example 2 objects(Meshes)
but `intersections = rayCaster.intersectOctreeObjects( meshesSearch);`  
sometimes (I guess randomly) shows 1 intersection, and sometimes 0. however there should be at least 1 intersection...
<br/>
I'm using adding nodes from vertices

Comment: Maybe you need to pass the recursive flag? `raycaster.intersectOctreeObjects( objects, true )`. If not, you will just have to use the debugger to slowly step through the code and see if you can find the problem. Test with a very simple case, so you can verify the logic.

Comment: @WestLangley, could you move your comment to answers. It perfectly does what I want to do!

Comment: That's OK. Just answer your own question and show the relevant snippets of code that worked for you. You can accept your own answer. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @WestLangley recommended the solution of this problem was to build octree.

```
octree=new THREE.Octree({
      undeferred:false,
      depthMax:Infinity,
      objectsThreshold:8,
      overlapPct:0.15
    } );
```

and search it

```
var meshesSearch=octree.search( rayCaster.ray.origin, radiusSphere, true, rayCaster.ray.direction );
```

However, to have specific intersection we need to provide the recursive flag

```
raycaster.intersectOctreeObjects( objects, true )
```

I ended up with more complicated processing of my specific case however this was enough to solve the problem at that moment.